# How do I make a button click event to be switch button?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void demoAlertToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     demoAlertToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Red;
     timer1.Stop();
}
```

On the first click it will change the color to red and will stop timer1 now i want that if i click again on the button it will change the color back to it's original color Black and will continue timer1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the [`Timer.Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx) property and make your changes, for sample:

```
private void demoAlertToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (timer1.Enabled) // timer is running
    {
        demoAlertToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        timer1.Stop();
    }
    else  // timer is stopped
    {
        demoAlertToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        timer1.Start();
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `"Start"` it sets Enabled to `TRUE`, `"Stop"` sets it to `FALSE`.

Is it the one you wanted?

```
private void demoAlertToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(timer1.Enabled)
    {
        demoAlertToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        timer1.Stop();
    }
    else
    {
        demoAlertToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        timer1.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or one shorter:

```
private void demoAlertToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;
    demoAlertToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = timer1.Enabled ? Color.Black : Color.Red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider configuring your toolstrip button into a "toggle" button, i.e. one that stays depressed when clicked until it is clicked another time. That way the user will have a visual clue whether your action/timer is currently enabled or not:

```
demoAlertToolStripMenuItem.CheckOnClick = true; // this makes the button a "toggle" one

void demoAlertToolStripMenuItem_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (demoAlertToolStripMenuItem.Checked)
    {
        // do one action, e.g. start the timer
        …
    }
    else
    {
        // undo the action, e.g. stop the timer
        …
    }
}
```